# On a rule-based system, how you deal with lack of facts?

Tags: rule-engine, fuzzy-logic

I'm studying in college about rule-based system, and I want to know if I have the rules of my system, but the facts are incomplete what I can do?
For example:
Rules:

```
r1: f1 and f2 then f3
r2: f3 then f4
r3 f4 then f5

Facts: {f1}

Objective: f5
```

To reach f5 I need the f2 but in my problem to solve I don't have it and my teacher says its right I have to think, but I tried and nothing so, what you can do when you don't have a fact that is needed?

I tried think of it but i feel i lack of information about the topic.